# Get undefined on list pick

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have dropdown list that calls a javascript function when a selection is made. But when that is done, the function says the picked item is undefined. The html is:

```
     <div class="main">Color Options:&nbsp;
     <select name="color_type"  id="colorTypesList" style="width:170px" onchange="javascript:return ChangeColorType(this)" 
       class="form-control">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">Standard Vinyl</option>
     <option value="1">Speciality Vinyl</option>
     <option value="2">Metallic Vinyl</option>
     <option value="3">Ultra Metallic Vinyl</option>
     </select>
     </div>
     <div id="picked"> </div>
```

The javascript is

```
    function ChangeColorType(item) {
      var id = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;        
      $("#picked").text("picked "+id);
    }
```

I added it here: https://jsfiddle.net/bgtLa29d/ but it isn't working at all. I may not have the proper includes but I don't know how to do that. But on my computer, the function is accessed but the picked value is always undefined.

Would someone take a look, please?

Comment: It's working to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a scope-related issue in your fiddle. jsfiddle by default wraps the code with a load handler, so the function becomes *private*.

```
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
 function ChangeColorType(item) {
       var id = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;        
       $("#picked").text("picked "+id);
    } 
}//]]>
```

You should select the `No wrap - in <body>` or `No wrap - in <head>` option on the JavaScript panel and your code will work!

Comment: I made that change to the fiddle and it is working now but the same code is failing for me locally. Is there a jquery include that is required that I might be missing? I'm including jquery-2.2.3.

Comment: I got it to work. The code is being handled with ajax and the javascript function was in the ajax file. I moved it to the main file and it is working now. I appreciate the quick help since it allowed me to find the problem.